# Simulating navigation bar in attribute table of ArcMap using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, attribute-table, navigation

I want to focus on specific record in the attribute table when it is open.
I have made several experiments with SearchCursor but that just selects the record, even focusing on the feature on the map but it does not focus on the record in the attribute table.

In conclusion, I want to simulate the navigation bar to the bottom of the attribute table..

[image: navigation bar in attribute table]

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

From [What is ArcPy?](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy/what-is-arcpy-.htm):

> ArcPy is a site package that builds on (and is a successor to) the
>   successful arcgisscripting module. Its goal is to create the
>   cornerstone for a useful and productive way to perform geographic data
>   analysis, data conversion, data management, and map automation with
>   Python.

It does not include functionality to build the ArcMap application, and to do any manipulation of the Attribute window of ArcMap you would need to look at ArcObjects.

Comment: I have never used ArcObjects ever before. Maybe I should start doing so because the functionality I am looking for is really necessary to me.